# adding data to django models from excel file

Tags: django

I need to feed the django models with data from excel file when the file is uploaded. This excel file contains weekly schedule of employees so the data changes evey week. How do I update the database every time the file is uploaded??

Comment: Are you tried, what you are seek ? show us some code, it will help us to debug further ..

Comment: You can use `xlrd` if you want to write some custom code, or you can use `django_import_export` package.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way out is to use [django-import-export](https://github.com/bmihelac/django-import-export) which is a library that does just that and comes with admin interface integration.